# Issue in Pushing ABPersonViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook

i am having trouble in pushing ABpersonViewController when the name is from user added then everything works perfectly but when name is from default simulator entries then its not working i will explain in detail in code

```
-(void)showPersonViewController:(NSString *)name  
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSString *string = name;
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    CFStringRef cfstringRef = (CFStringRef)string;
    NSArray *peoplee = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, cfstringRef);
    NSLog(@"%@",peoplee);
    // 1ST QUESTION when contact is from defalut contact nslog is null but when from user added then it has value I dont understand why this is happening 
    if ((peoplee != nil) && [peoplee count])
    {
        ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[peoplee objectAtIndex:0];
        ABPersonViewController *picker = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
        picker.personViewDelegate = self;
        picker.displayedPerson = person;

        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Could not find Appleseed in the Contacts application"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I replaced your code of converting NSString To CFStringRef :

This is if you are using ARC:

```
 CFStringRef cfstringRef = (__bridge_retained  CFStringRef)string;
```

But it seems you are not, so for Non ARC:

> CFStringRef cfstringRef = (CFStringRef)string;

```
-(void)showPersonViewController
{
  ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
  NSString *string = @"Appleseed";
  CFStringRef cfstringRef = (CFStringRef)string;
  NSArray *peoplee = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, cfstringRef);
  NSLog(@"%@",peoplee); // does not print null if you have Appleseed as your contact
  if ((peoplee != nil) && [peoplee count])
  {
    ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[peoplee objectAtIndex:0];
    ABPersonViewController *picker = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
    picker.personViewDelegate = self;
    picker.displayedPerson = person;
    // Allow users to edit the person’s information
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
  }
  else
  {
    // Show an alert if "Appleseed" is not in Contacts
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:@"Could not find Appleseed in the Contacts application"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
  }
  CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

Comment: My friend Puneet you have solved my first problem +1 for this but do you have any idea about second question?

Comment: I have a contact name Mike Smith in my contacts, if I pass that instead of Appleseed, the code still works.

Comment: when there is name like Kate Bell as there is space in name so its not working how to deal with this ?

Comment: let me try some other name

Comment: yes i checked it you are right bro when the contact is added by user then its working but its not working for those default added contact in simulator you reset your smulator and then add one of default added contact name it will not work

Comment: This is strange,. Seems the default contacts are secured from searching. If I search a default contact in Contacts app in simulator, it does not search anything as well. I am looking for some explanation.

Comment: if you find solution for this please post here i am searching too

Comment: everything is working perfectly in my app except this default contacts

Comment: @Punnet did you find anything?

Comment: Nopes. I have gone through Apple documentation and other stuff on net. The thing is not coming up anywhere. I am searching more though. If you want to go on with your application and dont hamper your work, you could show only the contacts added by user on the tableview.

Comment: how to do that like showing only user added contacts? is there any way to distinguish between user added contact and default contact i dont think so